# Javascript: How exactly do network IOs impact the execution?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, networking, io

Let's consider a Javascript web app that opened a network data channel with another peer. Now, let our app send 10 (relatively large) messages:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    otherPeer.channel.send(message[i])
}
```

From my understanding of the Javascript event loop, this will not block the code execution but will just queue some IO tasks. But intuitively, those messages will take some time to be sent, probably some time relative to the available upload capacity.

So which component will be responsible to buffer and spend the time to send these messages? Will it be in a completely separate thread, or process, or will it also affect and delay the Javascript Event queue? Even if the messages are really big and the network slow?

What happens (in term of CPU usage and execution threads) if instead of sending 10 messages, I'd send thousands of them?
What should the Javascript app do to avoid overwhelming the network?

I am interested in this because I'm trying to build a simulated/virtualized environment for my Javascript app. In order to run relevant simulations, I need to virtualize the network channels of the running agents and thus, I need to understand precisely how sending messages through the network will impact the execution of the agent.

Comment: Not an answer for this specific question but in general, JavaScript does not have multiple threads, so everything happens in a single thread (it's just that JavaScript is smart and spends time on background tasks when there's no active foreground tasks).

Comment: Javascript is single threaded.  It will send all 10 messages sequentially, not concurrently.  The speed of the sent messages depends on how quickly the code can be processed.  It will create a new execution context for each send.  To prove it, send those messages to a local database with a reasonable connection pool.  Do it 100,000 times.  You won't flood the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So does that mean that each message will be added to the event queue? And that they will be sent as part of the main Javascript event loop?